# Downloading packages with pip on OSX El Capitan

Tags: python, osx-elcapitan

I have been having a lot of issues lately downloading Python packages. I use a Mac and run OS X El Capitan v. 10.11.6. It seems that with the El Capitan upgrade, you are not allowed to install new packages to the the `usr/bin/` location unless you are the root user. However, when I enable root user, I still get errors. I have downloaded Python to `usr/local/bin` with homebrew, but that doesn't seem to fix anything because when I run python programs from my terminal, it says it cannot find the packages in the `usr/bin` location. It seems that python programs are executed from one location, `usr/bin` but I am only permitted to install packages to the `usr/local/bin`.

In short, my python programs try to run from one location, but all the packages I need are in another location. At least that is what appears to be going on to the best of my understanding. Just looking for some insight here as this has become very frustrating! Thanks!

Comment: I'd advise using a virtualenv, which will also separate dependencies for different projects or versions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of reasons why this could have happened, so I recommended checking that python is in your PATH, and in the future using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) and/or [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) can help you.

How do you check is python is in your PATH?

```
echo $PATH
```

in your terminal, and check if python path is in that string.

If it is not in your PATH, you have to add it either by adding it to .bashrc or .zshrc is you use zsh.

How do you add python to your path in the rc files?
You add it to the end of the current PATH value. For example,

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"
```

then you should be able to type `python` in your terminal and use the python shell in your terminal.